# YouTube iframe in Cordova app: "This video is unavailable"

Tags: android, cordova, youtube-api, hybrid-mobile-app

In Cordova app for Android I have some YouTube iframes like this:

```
<iframe class="lg-video-object lg-youtube" width="560" height="315" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/XCUZSS54drI?wmode=opaque&amp;autoplay=1&amp;enablejsapi=1&amp;modestbranding=1&amp;showinfo=1&amp;rel=0&amp;controls=1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen=""></iframe>
```

Video is playing in desktop and mobile browsers but in the app it shows an error: "This video is unavailable" in both Android 7.0 device and Android 4.4 emulator.

I have following lines in index.html:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="img-src * 'self' data: https: http:; media-src * blob:; connect-src * ws: wss: http: https: 'self'">
```

and in config.xml:

```
<access origin="*" />
<allow-navigation href="*" />
<allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
<allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
<allow-intent href="tel:*" />
<allow-intent href="sms:*" />
<allow-intent href="mailto:*" />
<allow-intent href="geo:*" />
```

Cordova Android platform version is  7.0.0

Comment: Have you checked the version of your mobile YouTube app? Is it version 4.2.16?

Comment: YouTube app version on my mobile is 13.14.55. But I don't think it is responsible for playing videos in WebView iframe.

Comment: @Julia Did you get a solution to this?

Comment: @MSD no. But I noticed that the problem appears with music videos, probably the copyright issue. Regular videos are playing.

Comment: How can I filter out failing videos like this from the API search result? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8EzdmE4Ewqk